# Retorno de condição IF incorreta

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Faço uma requisição na api para pegar uns dados, e depois faço um forEach e dou o resultado para uma variável `this.DadosQueTaNaTela` logo depois eu faço outra requisição em outra api para pegar os dados e faço um forEach e o resultado dou para `this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson` sendo que eu preciso criar forEach dentro de forEach pq ele não da o resultado esperado.

O dado que vem nas duas variáveis sao strings. Ex.: `this.DadosQueTaNaTela = 15` e `this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson = 15`

Com isso eu faço uma condição if:

```
        this.grav.forEach(variable => {
            this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson = variable
            if (this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI == this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson.FI) {
                console.log('Dados iguais')
                console.log(this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI)
            }else{
              console.log('Dados diferentes')
              console.log(this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI)
            }
        })
```

Os dados que estou comparando são iguais, ou seja, deveria apenas mostrar no console a mensagem "Dados iguais", mas mostra no console tudo que ta no else também.

Alguém sabe o porquê desse problema?

***Obs.: vou colocar o código completo que vem antes do if para ter uma noção melhor***

```
this.MetaService.FiliaisMetaDiarias().subscribe(
  data => {
    const response = (data as any)
    this.objeto_retorno = JSON.parse(response._body);

    this.fil.length = 0
    this.filMetade.length = 0
    this.filNaoAtingida.length = 0


    this.objeto_retorno.forEach(element => {

      this.tots = element.TOTAL
      element.TOTAL = (element.TOTAL * 100).toFixed(3) + '%'
      element.TOTAL = element.TOTAL.toString().replace(".", ",")

      if (this.tots >= this.MetaAtingida) {

        this.fil.push({
          FI: element.FILIAL,
          porc: element.TOTAL
        });

        this.mainColor = 'MetaAtingida'

        this.fil.forEach(element => {
          this.DadosQueTaNaTela = element
        })

        this.MetaService.CheckOrderGet().subscribe(
          data => {
            const response = (data as any)
            this.obj = JSON.parse(response._body)

            this.obj.forEach(element => {
              this.grav = element
            })


          }, error => {
            console.log('error')
            console.log(error)
          }

        )
```

**RESULTADO QUE APARECE NO CONSOLE ANTES DO IF**

***O valor 36 é o que ta nas duas API's***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**VALOR DENTRO DO IF**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tenta com 3 iguais ===

Comment: Eu já tentei e mesmo assim não vai, ele sempre mostra o else

Comment: Converte pra numero antes do if

Comment: Continua do mesmo jeito, mostrando o else com os mesmos dados

Comment: Os números não são iguais então. Usa os 3 iguais e converte os dois pra números. Nao tem como dar errado.

Comment: @EduardoVargas se quer comparar o valor simplesmente, se com `==` não deu certo, com  `===` é que não funcionar com certeza :)

Comment: Nao funciona com nenhum dos dois

Comment: Ele além de mostrar os dados iguais que sao: 24, 25 ele tambem mostra esses dados no else além dos que nao sou iguais

Comment: Dá um `console.log(this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI, this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson.FI)` e coloca aqui o resultado

Comment: O laço forEach deve estar entrando nas duas condições, pois deve estar fazendo mais de uma comparação. Digamos que ele vai dar 2 voltas: na primeira 15 == 15 irá mostrar `dados iguais`, e na segunda volta, digamos 15 == 24, irá mostrar `Dados diferentes`.

Comment: @sam e como faço pra isso parar? pq eu preciso do forEach pra conseguir acessar os dados que ta no array individualmente

Comment: Antes de if (this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI == this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson.FI) {

Coloque o 
 console.log(this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI)
 console.log(this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson.FI)
E mostre o resultado que apareceu no console

Comment: Pronto. Coloquei a foto mostrando o resultado na pergunta @HerbertJunior

Comment: @Maria então pelo que eu entendi, ele passa no if e no else? Ou apenas no else?

Comment: Ele passa nos dois, mas aí ele só deveria mostrar os resultados corretos. No if é pra mostrar os diferentes, que é só o 04, e no else mostrar o igual que é o 34. Só que ele só da resultado na ultima vez, como mostra a imagem e nao já de primeira

Comment: Seria interessante diferenciar a nomenclatura das variáveis, pois elas estão se repetindo dentro do mesmo bloco e pode trazer inconsistência . Ex: response, element.

Comment: @Maria this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson e  this.DadosQueTaNaTela, ambos são arrays? E você quer comparar o que tem em um e não no outro?

Comment: @DuilioBenjoino fiz isso e deu no mesmo.

Comment: @HerbertJunior exatamente! Aí eu faço um map nos dois pra fazer essa comparação

Comment: @Maria, olhe se ajuda a resposta .. pelo que eu entendi seria isso

Answer (score 0):

```
let array:any[] = [];

let exist:boolean = false;

this.DadosQueTaNaTela.forEach(apielement => {

  var api = apielement;
  existe = false;
  this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson.forEach(dadoselement => {

      var dados = dadoselement;

      if (!exite){

        if (dados == api){
            existe = true;
            array.push(dados);
        }

      }

  }
}
```

Agora esse método apenas encontra se tem algum valor igual no segundo vetor ... caso queira salvar o valor ou alguma coisa teria que implementar outra lógica.

Comment: mas onde esta o outro array? o `this.DadosQueTaNaTela`

Comment: @Maria ali, alterei, sendo que o segundo, vai ser o procurado e o primeiro vai ser o que vai procurar ...

Comment: @maria funcionou?

Comment: aparentemente sim...mas eu colocando um else deveria aparecer os que nao são iguais, certo? mas acaba aparecendo os iguais também

Comment: http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/psu34/9 esse é o resultado do else, onde deveria aparecer apenas os que nao sao iguais (o igual é o numero 24).
e esse http://pt-br.tinypic.com/r/24mylhf/9 é o resultado do if (onde deve aparecer os iguais)

Comment: @Maria Aqui no meu trabalho, é bloqueado esses sites de imagens hehe, pelo que eu pude ver no seu código o que ficou confuso foi o loop, e não o IF e ELSE ... por isso o que eu fiz funcionou, eu não fiz muita coisa, apenas refiz o loop.
E se funcionou, aceita como resposta :)

Comment: Mas meu código anterior faz o mesmo que o seu...eu coloquei na pergunta o problema que é, na sua resposta não tem...ele retorna o resultado nos dois, sendo que deveria ser só em um

Comment: @Maria acho que o problema está no fato de você não encerrar o laço assim que deu o resultado igual, como está dentro de um foreach, ele vai passar na condição de ser igual e logo após ele vai ser diferente... então após encontrar o igual, teria que ter um break; para poder acabar com o laço ... então ele realmente passa pelas 2 condições, porém não ao mesmo tempo ...  Então depois de passar pela condição de ser igual ele vai passar pela diferente... no seu código quem é a  variável "grav"?

Comment: grav é uma variavel do tipo any, que fica logo acima do constructor, eu só criei ela pra colocar o resultado do forEach nela

Comment: this.grav.forEach(variable => {
            this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson = variable
            if (this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI == this.OlhaDadosDaApiJson.FI) {
                console.log('Dados iguais')
                console.log(this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI)
            }else{
              console.log('Dados diferentes')
              console.log(this.DadosQueTaNaTela.FI)
            }
        })
Nesse trecho você está fazendo um laço nessa variavel ... @Maria, acho que o erro pode ser nessa logica ... para colocar um resultado em um vetor, precisa usar o this.vetor.push(valor) ...

Comment: Entao no lugar do forEach deveria ser um push?

Comment: Se você quiser inserir no o dado em um vetor, sim ... deveria utilizar o push

Comment: O que eu preciso é percorrer o array para conseguir pegar os dados separadamente

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer o que tem no array 1 que não tem no array 2 correto? E esse resultado teria que colocar em outro array ... certo?

Comment: exatamente isso que eu quero

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83123/discussion-between-herbert-junior-and-maria).

Comment: Eu alterei o método lá para adicionar o que achou igual num vetor a parte, só coloque o tipo do vetor = ao dos elementos, pq ele está como any[]

Comment: ele ta salvando só o igual, mas o que eu preciso é que ele salve os diferentes, entende?